# get average value of red channel from bitmap using Renderscript android

Tags: bitmap, renderscript

I'm currently working in an android application where i need to compute the average value of red channel in a bitmap and i just discovered Renderscript that has a fast way to access bitmap pixels.
However until now i modified google developer page's code and failed to do want i wanted and here is my code:

Sript:

```
int *sum;

uchar4 __attribute__ ((kernel)) invert(uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y){
uchar4 out = in;
sum[0] += in.r;
out.r = 255 - in.r; 
out.g = 255 - in.g;
out.b = 255 - in.b;
return out;
}
```

so what i try to do above is sum up all red value in the pointer "sum" and in java code:

```
int [] sum = new int[2];
Allocation data = Allocation.createSized(rs, Elelement.I32(rs), sum.length, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
data.copy1DRangeFrom(0, sum.length, sum);

Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(input.getWith(), input.getHeight(), input.getConfig);
Allocation in = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, input);
Allocation out = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, output);

ScriptC_root root = new ScriptC_root(rs);
root.bind_sum(sum);
root.forEach_invert(in, out);
out.copyTo(output);
data.copyTo(sum); //Here is where i am trying to geck the sum

//so i try to compute the average 
float avg = sum[0] / input.getWidth() * input.getHeight();
```

For the bitmap invert operation i am getting exactly the expected result
The value i get at avg is too small(under 150) while the input bitmap is a completely red image.
I tried  simply to increment the pointer *sum in the script to check if the foEach loop is accessing exactly the same number of pixels every time and in every run i get different number.
A help about how to do this properly would be the most welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** this code is strictly related to the main question, how to get the average of a channel.

What you want to achieve can be done in this way:

1) RenderScript

```
#pragma rs java_package_name(net.hydex11.channelaverageexample)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed
#pragma version(1)

// Use two global counters
static int totalSum = 0;
static int counter = 0;

// One kernel just sums up the channel red value and increments 
// the global counter by 1 for each pixel
void __attribute__((kernel)) addRedChannel(uchar4 in){

 rsAtomicAdd(&totalSum, in.r);
 rsAtomicInc(&counter);

}

// This kernel places, inside the output allocation, the average
int __attribute__((kernel)) getTotalSum(int x){
    return totalSum/counter;
}

void resetCounters(){

    totalSum = 0;
    counter = 0;

}
```

**Note:** I used the `rsAtomic*` functions because, if you are working on a global variable from different threads, you have to use thread-safe operations (e.g. [Thread safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety)).

2) Java side

```
private void example() {

    RenderScript mRS = RenderScript.create(this);

    // Loads example image
    Bitmap inputImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.houseimage);
    Allocation inputAllocation = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRS, inputImage);

    // Allocation where to store the sum result (for output purposes)
    Allocation sumAllocation = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.I32(mRS), 1);

    // Init script
    ScriptC_average scriptC_average = new ScriptC_average(mRS);

    // If you have a cycle, you have to reset the counters on each cycle
    //scriptC_average.invoke_resetCounters();

    // 1. Execute sum kernel
    scriptC_average.forEach_addRedChannel(inputAllocation);

    // 2. Execute a kernel that copies the sum into an output allocation
    scriptC_average.forEach_getTotalSum(sumAllocation);

    int sumArray[] = new int[1];
    sumAllocation.copyTo(sumArray);

    // E.g. simple output can be 66
    Log.d("AverageExample", String.format("The average of red channel is %d", sumArray[0]));

}
```

Reference: [RenderScript: parallel computing on Android, the easy way](https://hydex11.net/renderscript_parallel_computing_on_android_the_easy_way)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to answer my question and your code is working well. The thing is i am using this code in an application(measure heartrate) where i am receiving new frame every 50 millisecond and i compute the average of that channel using your code(thanks for it again). But seems i have a memory allocation problem. After running few frames it returns this error:                    08-12 18:40:12.886 18448-19552/com.example.aa.rendersrc V/RenderScript: 
         com.example.aa.rendersrc A/libc: mmap failed

Comment: Actually, the code I wrote is for a one-run. If you want to use it in a cycle, please look at the `resetCounters` function I just added.

Comment: Thanks for everything, i fixed the error problem :)

Comment: Sorry to ask again, i have a last question. I want to get the average as float so that i can get more precision. i changed totalSum to float and also the function getTotalSum to float, i also changed the element type to F32 while initializing the allocation object so no errors. just i am getting 0 all the time as result. Any idea what i did wrong?

Comment: You can just cast the values, so `(float)totalSum/(float)counter`. This way you will not get 0.