# Detect taken images brightness/darkness level - using Android CameraX

Tags: android, image, android-camerax

I'm using `CameraX` to capture images on Android.
I wanted to implement feature that would analyze captured images brightness/darkness level - if image is too dark/bright.

Is there some elegant way of doing this? Maybe some powerful light library that is meant for this?

Current approach is a code pieces that was found somewhere on Stackoverflow:

```
public static boolean isDark(Bitmap bitmap){
    boolean dark=false;

    float darkThreshold = bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight()*0.45f;
    int darkPixels=0;

    int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight()];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());

    for(int pixel : pixels){
        int color = pixels[i];
        int r = Color.red(color);
        int g = Color.green(color);
        int b = Color.blue(color);
        double luminance = (0.299*r+0.0f + 0.587*g+0.0f + 0.114*b+0.0f);
        if (luminance<150) {
            darkPixels++;
        }
    }

    if (darkPixels >= darkThreshold) {
        dark = true;
    }
    long duration = System.currentTimeMillis()-s;
    return dark;
}
```

Second approach is to use SensorManager `TYPE_LIGHT`. Any more ideas/approaches?

Comment: Renderscript is likely to work much faster as it will be GPU accelerated, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908491/get-average-value-of-red-channel-from-bitmap-using-renderscript-android, which is pretty close to what you're asking (though it only looks at RED channel, easy to modify to measure luminance

Answer (score 0):

The more efficient way would be calculating the luminance without converting the output to Bitmap.

```
private final ImageAnalysis.Analyzer mAnalyzer = image -> {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().remaining()];
    image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer().get(bytes);
    int total = 0;
    for (byte value : bytes) {
        total += value & 0xFF;
    }
    if (bytes.length != 0) {
        final int luminance = total / bytes.length;
        // luminance is the value you need.
    }
    image.close();
};
```

[Source: CameraX test app source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/CameraControllerFragment.java)

Comment: What should be the correct exposure value of the luminance?